# Is it possible to send UDP/TCP packets from Android to Arduino Ethernet shield?

Tags: android, tcp, udp, arduino, ethernet

Currently I am trying to send some UDP packets to the Arduino.
I set up an Android device, PC, router, and Arduino Ethernet shield. (The Ethernet shield is connected to the router via an Ethernet cable and Android to catch Wi-Fi from the router.) 
Is it possible to send some data (UDP) from the Android to the Arduino shield?

Answer (score 2):

For the Arduino there are several code samples at the following links:

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServerBegin

Answer (score 1):

A few notes and suggestions. Arudino has extensive support for UDP. Type 'Arudino UDP' (without the single quotes) into Google and you will find many references, examples, etc.

The Android side is a different matter. Google searches strongly suggest that this is possible. However, I have never implemented any Android UDP code.

In any case, make sure you have Wireshark up and running for debugging your data flows. Be sure to set a UDP filter to get rid of all of the extraneous traffic.